# Laravel sync() pivot column with an array of values as extra field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables and a pivot table:

**Company**

```
roleuserable_id
roleuserable_type
```

**User**

```
user_id
```

**Role**

```
role_id
```

Starting from the company i have relationship

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->morphToMany('App\Role', 'roleuserable', 'role_user')->withPivot('user_id');
}
```

How can i achieve something similar to this knowing that the block below will result with an error:

```
// The company
$company = Company::first();

// Sync data
$data = [
  1 => [[user_id => 1], [user_id=>2]],
  2 => [[user_id => 1], [user_id => 3]]
];

// Data sync
$company->roles()->sync($data);
```

Comment: Assuming the keys *1* and *2* from the `$data` array are IDs of companies?

Comment: @TheFallen nope. They are role id. Actually accepting multiple users with same role for a morphing entity (in this case company).

Answer (score 0):

Edit-

Ok, after your comment I realized the approach we are following for this is completely wrong. We must make a separate **Roles BelongsToMany Users** and **Roles BelongsToMany Companies** and vice versa....

```
role_user
| role_id | user_id  |
|   1     |    1     |
|   1     |    2     |
|   2     |    1     |
|   2     |    3     |

company_role
| role_id | company_id  |
|   1     |      1      |
|   2     |      1      |
```

which can be selected by

```
$companyUsers = $company->roles()->flatMap(function($role) {
                  return $role->users;
                });

$userCompanies = $user->roles()->flatMap(function($role) {
                  return $role->companies;
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @prateekkathal. The only issue i see here is the relationship in the "User" model for getting all "Companies" with "Roles".

Comment: @whym.e Just edited my answer... can you have a look at it. I think this should work for you :)

Comment: Hm...Here we have two tables, but the issue is that the user can have different role for different company. I.E. admin [1], editor[2] etc. Following this example i may stuck with duplicates on roles_id for users. I'm thinking on going with a pivot model solution with regular insert.